# How to go about a regression analysis on a study design that is between and within subjects and has repeated measures?

Tags: repeated-measures

I have 2 questions I'm trying to answer.
(1) w/in subject: How does a person's experience with (A) change overtime?
(2) btwn subjects: That person belongs to a certain group. How do groups' experience with (A) compare to each other?

How can I go about answering these questions using SAS? If not with SAS, what about R or SPSS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.